# Strong chains of uncountable functions and cardinal characteristics

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, cardinal-characteristics

A family of functions $\langle f_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\rangle$ from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_1$ is called a *strong chain* if $\alpha<\beta<\kappa\Longrightarrow \{\xi<\omega_1: f_\beta(\xi)\leq f_\alpha(\xi)\}$ is finite.  It is a result of Koszmider [1] that the existence of a strong chain of length $\omega_2$ is consistent. (Another presentation of this result is in [2], using a technique due to Neeman.)

The existence of a strong chain of length $\kappa$ implies that $\kappa\leq\frak{c}$ (as the restrictions of the functions to the first $\omega$ places are distinct), so in particular, if there is a strong chain of length $\omega_2$ then the Continuum Hypothesis fails.

> Does the existence of a strong chain of length $\omega_2$ have any
>   influence on the configuration of standard cardinal characteristics of
>   the continuum?

[1] *Koszmider, Piotr*, [**On strong chains of uncountable functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02803525), Isr. J. Math. 118, 289-315 (2000). [ZBL0961.03039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0961.03039).

[2]  *Veličković, Boban; Venturi, Giorgio*, [**Proper forcing remastered**](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/1110.0610), Cummings, James (ed.) et al., Appalachian set theory 2006–2012. Based on the Appalachian set theory workshop series during the period 2006–2012. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-60850-4/pbk). London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 406, 331-362 (2013). [ZBL1367.03094](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1367.03094).

Comment: so Chang's Conjecture keeps this $\kappa$ small ($\aleph_1$) and CC is c.c.c indestructible so basically this $\kappa$ cannot bound any cardinal invariant. For the other direction, is it known if it is possible to have $\kappa\geq \omega_3$?

Comment: I don't the answer to the $\omega_3$ question.  What I'm really curious about is if the existence of the strong $\omega_2$-chain implies that some cardinal characteristics must be greater than $\omega_1$ (we know that $\mathfrak{c}>\omega_1$, for example).

Comment: It seems that the forcing to add such an $\omega_2$ strong chain is strongly proper, so at least we can exclude invariants like $\mathfrak{b}$ (and many others) since no strongly proper forcing can add a dominating real (any real lives in a Cohen sub-extension but Cohen forcing can't add a dominating real).

Comment: Yes. And once you have a long strong chain, it will still exist in further ccc extensions, so you can achieve further configurations, say by adding a small dominating family.